# Very simple procedure statement from school slide. I want to know how it works

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure HelloWorld(s varchar)
as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(s);
end;

-------- click execute button now

exec HelloWorld('Hello');
```

The codes above is from the school slide. The first code is shown as 'procedure created' which means good to go. When I execute it by using 'exec HelloWorld(‘Hello’);', it shows errors. May I ask some of question regarding this code please?

1) Why it does not work when I execute it?

2) I know that 's' is a parameter, and 'varchar' is the datatype for 's'. However, the code requires that print 's'. As I can see, there is nothing to assigned on 's'. Then, how can the code runs the value of 's' in 'dbms_output.put_line(s);'?

3)Can anybody just explain what is the basic function for each single word?

Comment: "*it shows errors*" - and what exactly is that error?

Comment: ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-06550: line 1, column 18: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "‘" when expecting one of the following: 
( ) - + case mod new not null <an identifier> 
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> 
table continue avg count current exists max min prior sql 
stddev sum variance execute multiset the both leading 
trailing forall merge year month day hour minute second 
timezone_hour timezone_minute timezone_region timezone_abbr 
time timestamp interval date 
<a string literal with character set specification>

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing wrong. The procedure compiles without errors (not surprisingly, since it is correct), and the call works perfectly fine on my machine. Are you sure you are simply executing the function, and not more code? Then - in Oracle, get in the habit of using the varchar2 data type (you will learn later why). The 's' in the function definition is a placeholder - it is assigned when you "execute" the function. It is given the value you put in parentheses when you call the function - in this case 'Hello'. This is how functions work in all of computing, not just Oracle.

Comment: It's a long shot but.... did you copy/paste this? because if you are provided code in a weird font it messes up the single quote character. The character you pasted in your comment is *‘* but thats not a valid character - you need to use *'* instead. I know it's hard to see the difference but paste those two things into word and look at them - they're different characters. Alternatively, go into your code in your editort and make sure you press the ' key rather than copy paste.

Comment: Okay thank you everybody I got it.

Comment: Especially, thank you mathguy. You got the answer!